If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $|\lambda|^{2}\le\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|M(T)_{j,k}|^2$
This is a problem from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th Edition, problem 19 of section 6A:

Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $T\in L(V)$. Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then
$$|\lambda|^{2}\le\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|M(T)_{j,k}|^2,$$
where $M(T)_{j,k}$ denotes the entry in row $j$, column $k$ of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

The operator $T$ in the question might be either complex or real. The closest upper bound I could come up with is $|\lambda|^{2}\le n\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}
|M(T)_{j,k}|^2$ where the sum of the absolute value of the squared entries of the $j$th row is greater or equal than for any other row. And here's the proof:
Let $A=M(T)$, by Gershgorin disk theorem each eigenvalue is contained within some gershgorin disk of $A$. Assume $\lambda$ is contained within the $j$th gershgorin disk:
$$|\lambda|-|A_{j,j}|\le|\lambda-A_{j,j}|\le\sum_{k=1\\ k\neq j}^{n}|A_{j,k}|$$
$$\begin{align} |\lambda|^2 &\le (\sum_{k=1}^{n}|A_{j,k}|)^2 \\ &\le n\sum_{k=1}^{n}
|A_{j,k}|^2 \end{align}$$
I've seen similar problems to this but their solution involved traces and more advanced linear algebra that aren't discussed at this point in Axler's book, so is there an elementary solution to this problem in the sense that it involves at most the gershgorin disk theorem and some manipulating of inequalities like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?
Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Pouya The trace is discussed in the final chapter of Axler's book, whereas the Gershgorin circle theorem is not discussed in his book at all. It's strange, then, that you would opt to forgo one in favor of the other.

@Pouya Interestingly, the same section of the 3rd edition does not have this problem in this section.

@BenGrossmann The Gershgorin disk theorem as well as this problem was added in the 4th edition of the book.

@Pouya Interesting. An alternative is to use the fact that $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle \leq \sum_{j,k} |A_{j,k}|^2$ for a unit vector $x$. I've been trying to show this using Cauchy Schwarz and the like but I'm getting stuck

@Pouya Actually, I figured it out. Edit to my question coming soon

@BenGrossmann There is a somewhat more general form of this problem presented at problem 20 of part 10A of the 3rd edition which is a section on trace, where this one eigenvalue is replaced by all eigenvalues repeated by their multiplicities however the basis is required to be an orthonormal basis.

There is a $v = (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbf{F}^n$ such that $A v = \lambda v$ and $||v||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 = 1$. Now we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
|\lambda|^2 = ||A v||^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \left| \sum_{k=1}^n a_k A_{j,k} \right|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n |A_{j,k}|^2 \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n |A_{j,k}|^2.
$$

Here's an approach that seems to meet your requirements.
I will address the complex case, but the corresponding computation in the real case is essentially the same.
Let $v$ denote an eigenvector of $T$ associated with $\lambda$. Let
$x$ denote the coordinate vector of $v$, i.e. let $x\in \Bbb C^n$ be such that $v = \sum_{j}x_j v_j$. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the Euclidean inner product. Without loss of generality, suppose that $v$ is normalized such that $\langle x,x\rangle = 1$. We find that
$$
\langle M(T) x, M(T)x \rangle = \langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle = |\lambda|^2 \langle x,x \rangle = |\lambda|^2.
$$
On the other hand, we note that $\langle x,x\rangle \leq 1$ implies that $|x_k| \leq 1$ for each $k$. Thus, we have
\begin{align}
|\lambda|^2 = \langle M(T) x, M(T)x \rangle &= 
\sum_{j=1}^n
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n M(T)_{j,k} x_k\right|^2
\\ & \leq 
\sum_{j=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^n \left|M(T)_{j,k} x_k\right|^2
\\ & = 
\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n |M(T)_{j,k}|^2  \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |M(T)_{j,k}|^2.
\end{align}
With that, we have shown that $|\lambda^2| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n |M(T)_{j,k}|^2$, which was what we wanted.

As Terran's answer here shows, the above inequality can also be shown using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, since
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n M(T)_{j,k} x_k\right|^2 \leq 
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |M(T)_{j,k}|^2\right)\cdot 
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 \right).
$$

Here is an approach using the trace.
The trick here is to notice that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n|M(T)_{j,k}|^2 &= 
\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \overline{M(T)_{k,j}}M(T)_{j,k} 
\\ & = \sum_{j=1}^n [M^*(T)M(T)]_{j,j}
\\ & = \operatorname{tr}(M^*(T)M(T)) = \operatorname{tr}(T^*T).
\end{align*}
Because the trace is basis invariant, it can be computed relative to any choice of basis. Select any orthonormal basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ such that $v_1$ is a unit eigenvector of $T^*$ associated with $\lambda$.  We find that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(T^*T) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle v_j, T^*Tv_j\rangle
\\ &= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle Tv_j, Tv_j \rangle
\\ & \geq \langle Tv_1, Tv_1 \rangle = \langle \lambda v_1, \lambda v_1 \rangle = |\lambda|^2 \|v_1\|^2 = |\lambda|^2,
\end{align}
which is what we wanted to show.
